Modifying Embed script
First, let me preface i am not a coder so my apologies if this is a simple fix and thanks in advance for any help.
A client sent an embed script for their email management platform:
<script
  src="https://cdn.virtuoussoftware.com/virtuous.embed.min.js"
  data-vform="44A98D87-F513-42CE-A87E-A697416AB843"
  data-orgId="5189"
  data-isGiving="false"
  data-dependencies="[]">
</script>

all good when i added except labels cannot be seen as I am using a black background and I need labels to be in white and need to add a bit more padding between label name and field, as well as change heading ("Join our mailing list") color and button color #e85d2f
https://amplifinapavalley.org/coming-soon

The  tags in the rendered document have a CSS class associated with them (i.e., <label class="v_r">).  You could modify the CSS for your document to modify the color and padding.   Something like label.v_r {padding-bottom: 2px; color:#fff;}.  You could do something similar for the other elements you mentioned.

I am not super familiar with Wordpress/Elementor, so I am going to make a couple assumptions here but let me know if something doesn’t work as intended.
The overall embed starts at this element:
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-e9a192c e-flex e-con-boxed e-con e-parent e-lazyloaded" data-id="e9a192c" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}">

All of these classes seem fairly generic to Elementor, except for elementor-element-e9a192c, so that would likely be a good target for our CSS, but I don’t know if it’s specific to this page, or this widget on any page, or even if it changes over time based on cache. So I won’t use it for now, but it would be a likely target if you needed to select the top level of the form. We don’t, in this case, so let’s look elsewhere.
A couple layers within, we can find this div:
<div data-virtuous-form="44A98D87-F513-42CE-A87E-A697416AB843">

That looks like a unique ID, so if we wanted to affect only this instance of the widget, I would probably use this as a selector. But I am guessing you want the same styles to apply if you use the embed on other pages, so instead I will target the data-virtuous-form attribute itself, which should be unique to this widget.
From there, since most of the styles you mentioned rely on CSS custom properties, we can simply change the values of each property on elements tagged with the above attribute, and they will bubble down to affect the relevant elements. The only exception being the padding on labels, which is not set at all out of the box, so we add a specific rule for that:


[data-virtuous-form] {
    --v-body-color: white;
    --v-heading-color: #e85d2f;
    --v-button-bg-color: #e85d2f;
}
[data-virtuous-form] label {
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}



